# How to set back-ground color of a selected color kendo ui grid programatically

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am displaying results in Kendo UI and giving the background colors for the users to set through Client Web Part properties.Below is my databound function

```
dataBound:   function(){
        $("#grid tr:odd").css("background-color", searchParams["c1"]);


            $("#grid tr:even").css("background-color", searchParams["c2"]);


            $("#grid tr:odd").hover(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", searchParams["c3"]);
            }, function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", searchParams["c1"]);
            });


            $("#grid tr:even").hover(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", searchParams["c4"]);
            }, function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", searchParams["c2"]);
            });


            **$("#grid tr").on('click', function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", searchParams["c5"]);
                $(this).css("border-color", searchParams["c5"]);
            } );**

    }
```

SearchParams is a function retrieving the colors chosen by user. I am able to set background color of rows(odd and even and their hover colors). But when i am trying to set the back-ground color of Selected row(**code in between**), this doesn't work. When the row colors are not added, selected row color works but when the row colors are added selected row color doesn't work. I understand that row colors are taking precende but not sure what to do about this.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely understand what are trying to achive or asking. But from what i grasp from the question, the solution you may try is utilizing **k-state-selected** class, this class will be added to the td that you click/select so here goes the code

```
  $("#grid tr").on('click', function () {
      if($(this).find("td .k-state-selected")){
          $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
      } 
  });
```

The thing is, it will only make the selected pink but the other you've already selected stay pink. Instead also try to utilize [kendo grid's change event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change) by adding this

```
change:function(e){
    $("#grid tr:odd").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#grid tr:even").css("background-color", "green");
    $("tr:has(td.k-state-selected)").css("background-color", "pink");
},
```

[Working Example Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/aVaNI)

Comment: Thank you very much Raharja

Comment: Hey i just checked, i am making row as selectable.
Could you please convert 
$("tr:has(td.k-state-selected)").css("background-color", "pink");
for a selected row.

Comment: I figured it out, the issue was because of hover and click event on same element.It looks like a conflict.. Thank you anyways